# WIFI scan and connect application on raspberry pi3

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

Good day everyone ! I just started working on a raspberry pi 3b and i'm also a newbee in programming, i have a project to create a c# custom GUI that scans available wifi networks and connect to them.

Now my problem is, the GUI that i created in visual studio 2019 in windows it scans and connect to networks but when i run it in my raspberry pi it doesn't scan any wifi networks.

I already tried adding .net core on my RPi but still it won't work.
Is there anyone here that can help me? Any tutorial or suggestions will do,thank you guys !

Here is my code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wifi = new Wifi();

        List<AccessPoint> aps = wifi.GetAccessPoints();

        foreach(AccessPoint ap in aps)
        {
            ListViewItem lvItem = new ListViewItem(ap.Name);
            lvItem.SubItems.Add(ap.SignalStrength + "%");
            lvItem.Tag = ap;

            lView_AP.Items.Add(lvItem);
        }
    }

    private void Btn_Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lView_AP.SelectedItems.Count > 0 && txtB_PW.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            ListViewItem selectedItem = lView_AP.SelectedItems[0];
            AccessPoint ap = (AccessPoint)selectedItem.Tag;

            if (connectToWifi(ap, txtB_PW.Text))
                lbl_Status.Text = "You connected successfully \nto the network " + ap.Name;
            else
                lbl_Status.Text = "Connection failed";
        }
        else
            lbl_Status.Text = "Please select a network \nor enter a password.";
    }
    private bool connectToWifi(AccessPoint ap, string password)
    {
        AuthRequest authRequest = new AuthRequest(ap);
        authRequest.Password = password;

        return ap.Connect(authRequest);
    }

    private void btn_disconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (wifi.ConnectionStatus == WifiStatus.Connected)
            wifi.Disconnect();
    }
}
```

}

[And here is how it looks when i run in my windows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jxvw.jpg)

and when I run it in my RPi it doesn't show any wifi networks.

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  The top answer has a lot of good info for you.  Show us your code, be more specific about what you are doing and how, and more clearly describe what happens when it doesn't work.  "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive.  If I told you "my car doesn't run", is that enough information for you to diagnose the issue?

Comment: Okay @amy, I'm sorry I'm new to this :(

Comment: It's okay.  Just edit your question with your code and a description of what it is actually doing, and we can try to help you out.

Comment: First: you must use and target .Net Core. Second, windows forms doesn't yet work on anything but windows (if I recall correctly, 3 may have changed that) so that won't work. Third: I'd suggest making this a command line app as a starting point. Then add gui later. Also, thanks for updating your question - we can be much more helpful that way.

Comment: I'm also going to assume you verified drivers and hardware is installed correctly and working and that the rpi isn't running Windows